# How to connect to remote MSSQL database using php 5.5.19

Tags: php, sql-server, dll, xampp, mssql-jdbc

I have had a problem trying to establish a connection to a MSSQL database I created in Microsoft SQL Server Manager 2008 R2 using php 5.5.19 in XAMPP.

In the php.ino configuration file under extensions, there is commented out a ';extension=php_mssql.dll'. I removed the comment and ran apache in the xampp control panel.
Naturally an error occurred stating ''PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '..\ext\php_mssql.dll cannot be found'. I looked in the ext directory and sure enough it wasn't there. I added the mssql.dll file from

www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?php_mssql

,but then I got an Entry Point not found error stating 'The procedure entry point php_body_write could not be located in the dll php5ts.dll'.

After further research, I discovered that mssql_connect was not working since PHP version 5.3: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php
I instead tried to use the 'sqlsrv_connect'' function, but I had to install the new drivers from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

After reading the readme, I saw that I needed the libraries php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll to work with xampp's php5ts.dll in the php folder.
I added the libraries in the php\ext folder and added corresponding extensions to the new dll's and restarted Apache.

I then got an system error 'The program can't start because MCVCP110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.' Obviously reinstalling isn't an option as I will lose my new dll's so I verified that MCVCP110.dll is in the php folder, which it was.

Please help, I really need to find a way to load the libraries with the 'sqlsrv_connect' function properly so I can connect to a MSSQL database.

Comment: What OS is your PHP server on? On Windows, I'd just run the PHP installer and click the checkbox to add the components. No need to download dlls from some shady source.

Comment: I am running it on Windows 7. Since php is packaged in xampp, I didn't have any options to load alternate dll's.  Is there a better web server service I can use on my local machine for testing?

Comment: You could install Apache, PHP, and MySQL separately rather than using XAMPP.

Comment: Best thing I did to connect was switch to Go. The drivers connect easily and it gives the coder far more versatility